# Query sql with hive without YARN

Tags: sql, hadoop-yarn, hiveql

I'm looking for a way to execute sql queries directly in the database through hive without going through YARN, I've ever seen a collaborator who did it.
This is because the percentage of yarn in the cluster is 100% for processing multiple tasks and I need to make a query that ends quickly.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Any query you run outside of YARN will still require memory and CPU resources potentially triggering OOMs on the cluster.

Comment: See, hive is not hadoop independent services which means it is not possible to run hive queries without providing it resources, which is basically done by YARN. Now, if you really don't want to use YARN for the resources, then you should be able to design a code where you can directly provide resources to your application without including YARN services.

Comment: ok, thank you for your replies

Comment: FYI: both Impala and Drill can run SQL queries on Hive tables and these run at least an order of magnitude faster than Hive but as stated, these have potential of affecting other processes that are running on the same systems since they're not regulated by YARN.